# How to delete a remote file using ssh?

Tags: php, file, ssh, rm

I am working on a project where we are using 2 VM's one is used as local and can be accessible and from this local VM, we need to access the remote VM. While working on this I am struck on a problem.There is a file in the remote in a directory.Every time a script gets executed the file gets loaded with new data and but I don't need that.I want the file to be deleted everytime before my script executed.

I have given the code below.

```
if($ssh = ssh2_connect('192.168.150.85', 22)) {
     if(ssh2_auth_password($ssh, 'someUserName', 'somePassword')) {
         $stream = ssh2_exec($ssh, "python file_scanner.py /home/nsadmin/$file_name");
         $stream = ssh2_exec($ssh, 'rm /home/nsadmin/file_scanned');
         stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
         $data = '';
         while($buffer = fread($stream, 4096)) {
             $data .= $buffer;
         }
         fclose($stream);
         echo $data; // user
     }
 }
```

Here we can see that after ssh connection,Iam ecxecuting some script and the result of this file gets appended in the file `file_scanned`.But when ever I execute the ssh connection I previous results are also coming.So I did `$stream = ssh2_exec($ssh, 'rm /home/nsadmin/file_scanned');` . But it is not working.

Any suggestions on how to change or modify my script so I can remove the file after execution of previous command.

Comment: try '$stream = ssh2_exec($ssh, 'rm -f  /home/nsadmin/file_scanned');'

Comment: @amit_183 file_scanned is normal file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be issue with permission I can say,

But this is solution you can give a try.

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
$stream = ssh2_sftp_unlink($sftp, '/home/nsadmin/file_scanned');
```

This is frequent thing, which we used for removing remote files.